# How to write a function to check a specific cell and return that cell's row in the spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Description:** I set up an email trigger so that when there is a change to the spreadsheet that meets the criteria below, it sends an email.

**What it currently does is:**
If you write 'Yes' in ANY cell, it triggers the email.

**What I'd LIKE it to do:**
ONLY if you write 'Yes' in column P, it triggers the email. Would also love for the email subject line to include which row the 'Yes' was written in.

Thank you in advance!!!

```
function sendApprovalEmail() {

var sheetNameToWatch = "Spreadsheet title"; //This is where my spreadsheet's title goes
var columnNumberToWatch = 16; //I think this should be column P?
var valueToWatch = 'Yes';

var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

var email = 'email@email.com'; //for my email    
var message = "Message text will go here";
var subject = "Subject text will go here";

if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue().toString().toLowerCase() == valueToWatch);
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 
}
```

Comment: Simple - in addition to referencing `getActiveCell()`, check for `getColumn()` on the resulting `Range` (cell is an instance of `Range`) and compare the returned `Number` to 1-based column reference (e.g. "A" Aequals to 1). In case you need row, there is a paired method `getRow()`

Comment: Actually, sorry about the first commen, the problem you are having is most likely (I missed the line with `if` statement) due to `if` statement not wrapping the `MailApp.sendEmail` call with curly brackets (or at least left without the `;`), essentially leaving it to be triggered unconditionally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

As a follow-up to comments, your `sendEmail()` method call is outside the scope of the `if` statement. There are three ways to write an `if` statement:

*Full syntax*

In my opinion, this is (albeit lacking in readability) the best way to write `if...else` statements to avoid debugging issues. Besides, the approach with block statements (wrapping everything with `{}`) allows to write multiple conditional statements into clauses:

`if(condition) { 
  conditional statements; 
}else {
  other conditional statements;
}`

*Short syntax*

The one you are using doesn't involve block statements, which can be desirable when executing *only one* conditional statemenet at a time, but you need to make sure that the `if` statement isn't closed before the conditional (that is there are no `;`, signifiying end of statement):

`if(condition)
  conditional statement
else
  another conditional`

*Shorthand syntax*

A conditional operator that can be used if you need to write a small, easily readable condition and, write the result to a variable (in the example full syntax is used with multiple conditions):

`condition1 ? onYes1 : condition2 ? onYes2`

**Solution**

As stated above, while using short syntax, you need to make sure that conditional statement is in scope of the `if` statement, thus you need to remove `;`, plus I would suggest separating checks for readability and using strict comparison:

```
var isSheet = sheet.getName() === sheetNameToWatch;
var isCol   = range.getColumn() === columnNumberToWatch;
var isValue = range.getValue().toString().toLowerCase() == valueToWatch;

if (isSheet && isCol && isValue) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
}
```

**Accessing row**

As for your second question, you can access row number with `getRow()` (or `getRowIndex()` as they are currently identical), the rest is pretty simple:

```
var curRow  = range.getRow();
var subject = 'Yes is in row '+curRow;
```

**Useful links**

1. Conditional operator [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator);
2. `If` statement [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else);
3. `getRow()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow);
4. `getRowIndex()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrowindex);

Comment: THANK YOU Oleg - Super helpful information in general and you solved my problem. Have a great weekend my friend.

Comment: Glad I could help - likewise!